# Search datatable with relationship values

Tags: jquery, laravel, search, datatable, server-side

I'm having a problem when I need to make a Search on my datatable. I have 4 columns with relation with another tables. On my controller I make a join to convert this data, so when I put some ID on search box, the filter works nicely, but I need make this search work only with the data who is presented on screen.

Here is my controller:

```
public function revList(Request $request)
{
    if(auth()->user()->can('Visualizar Revisão')){
        $revisoes = DB::table('revisao_ambientes')
            ->join('unidades', 'revisao_ambientes.unidade_id', '=', 'unidades.id')
            ->join('blocos', 'revisao_ambientes.bloco_id', '=', 'blocos.id')
            ->join('ambientes', 'revisao_ambientes.ambiente_id', '=', 'ambientes.id')
            ->join('users', 'revisao_ambientes.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select([
                'revisao_ambientes.unidade_id', 'unidades.name as unidade_name', 
                'revisao_ambientes.bloco_id', 'blocos.name as bloco_name', 
                DB::raw('CONCAT(ambientes.sala, " - ", ambientes.name) as ambiente_name'),
                'revisao_ambientes.user_id', 'users.name as user_name', 
                'revisao_ambientes.created_at as created_at',
                'revisao_ambientes.rev_id as rev_id',
            ]);                 

        return datatables()->of($revisoes) 
            ->addColumn('detalhes', function($row) {
                return '<a href="revisao/'. $row->rev_id .'" class="label label-info">Detalhes</a>';
            })
            //Try to make a filter by the building (Don't work)
            ->filterColumn('bloco_name', function($revisoes, $search) {
                $revisoes->where('blocos', 'LIKE', "{$search}%");
            })
            ->rawColumns(['detalhes'])
            ->make(true);
        }else{
            return view('errors.401');
        } 
    }
```

And here is my script of server side datatable:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#rev-datatable').DataTable({                 
  dom: 'Blfrtip',
      lengthMenu: [
          [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], 
          [10, 25, 50, 100, "Todos"]
        ],
      buttons: [
          { extend: 'copy', text: 'Copiar', exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            }},
          { extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel', exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
            }},
          { extend: 'pdf', text: 'PDF', orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL', exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
            }},             
      ],
      processing: true,
      Filter: true,
      lengthChange: true,
      lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "Todos"]],
      order:[[0,'desc']],
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: "{{ url('/revisao/rev-list') }}",
      columns: [
          { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },
          { data: 'user_name', name: 'user_id' },
          { data: 'unidade_name', name: 'unidade_id' },
          { data: 'bloco_name', name: 'bloco_id' },
          { data: 'ambiente_name', name: 'ambiente_id' }, 
          { data: 'detalhes', searchable: false, orderable: false},                 
             ] , 
    });
 });
```

What I need to do to make this works?

thanks advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, but I see a problem with your columns datatables option. The name property defines the name of the column in database, so change columns to this:

```
    columns: [
      { data: 'created_at', name: 'revisao_ambientes.created_at' },
      { data: 'user_name', name: 'users.name' },
      { data: 'unidade_name', name: 'unidades.name' },
      { data: 'bloco_name', name: 'blocos.name' },
      { data: 'ambiente_name' }, 
      { data: 'detalhes', searchable: false, orderable: false},                 
    ] ,
```

Also you don't need to define filterColumn for the bloco_name, but you need it for ambiente_name. That is why I removed name for ambiente_name in columns. Now remove filterColumn for bloco_name and add this:

```
->filterColumn('ambiente_name', function($revisoes, $search) {
    $sql = "CONCAT(ambientes.sala, ' - ', ambientes.name) like ?";
    $revisoes->whereRaw($sql, ["%{$search}%"]);
})
```

Since we inject $search by parameter binding there is no risk of SQL injection. 
Also please note that by mentioning the actual name of Database column, you are giving away information about your internal database structure, which is considered a security flaw. If you don't care then this is the solution but if you care write filterColumn for each column, and remove all "name" properties from datatables columns.

Comment: Tks, that's exacly what I need. Thank you soooo much.

I only edit this line:
** { data: 'ambiente_name', name: 'ambientes.name' },**